# Fetch images link in my account from Imgur

Tags: php, curl, imgur

I want to fetch image links in my account from Imgur.com.
I know that there is an API for this but I don't know where to start since there are examples for uploading images but not getting links.

I decided to use PHP and cURL but I tried and no luck.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Complete OAuth authentication. ([Here's an example](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/oauth/trunk/examples/twitter/fetchTimeline.php?revision=280252&view=markup) of using OAuth with twitter via the PECL OAuth extension)
2. Call http://api.imgur.com/2/account/images.json?count=70&page=1